# How can I /fill water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a huge amount of area that i need to fill relative to the player's place. I tried typing `/fill ~-80 69 ~-80 ~80 69 ~80 water` which basically fills a 160x160 hole 1 block deep relative to the player's coordinates, but that didn't work because it said `There is no such item id with name minecraft:water`

Comment: That works fine for me (and is supposed to so), are you using latest stable version of vanilla minecraft?

Comment: @QbsidianH20 I am using 1.8.2 prerelease 6. I guess they might have taken the feature out?

Comment: Taht's weird, I'm using same version too. Are you on singleplayer/multiplayer/realms?

Comment: @QbsidianH20 single player

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here, in either latest stable or latest snapshot.  Are you sure you typed the command correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try `/fill ~-80 69 ~-80 ~80 69 ~80 minecraft:flowing_water`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, so I wrote a mod to do it (and other things) for me.

Grab a copy of the Builder's Helper mod from http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php/topic,26612.0.html .  This needs Forge and minecraft 1.7.10 or 1.8.

This comes with a 'blueprint' called 'water-table'.  Give yourself the builder's wand item, use `/wand set water-table`, then right-click the wand in front of the hole you want to fill.  It will fill up with water to the level you clicked.  It will not remove any existing blocks from the world.

There is a similar plan to evaporate existing water, plans to build houses, glass dones, and so on, as well as copy existing structures.